# Mi app se detiene al instalarla en el movil

Tags: android

Estoy desarrollando una App y no muestra error alguno al compilarla e instalarla en mi movil... pero al ejecutarla me lanza el mensaje que "esta presentando problemas." luego deja de funcionar.

dejo mi app gradle y mi manifest xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name="MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jlmv.dbfirebase3"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Bienvenido, te invito a que realices un [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Además revisa [ask] que te da información para realizar una buena pregunta y obtener buenas respuestas. Es importante [edit] el formato de tu pregunta agregando lo que has tratado o investigado.

Comment: Hola Jose, nunca he visto el mensaje " "esta presentando problemas."" agrega la información con detalle y no olvides leer los documentos que te comparte Julian, saludos!